# How to add hash history url when redirecting from third party website with access token as hash key?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history, html5-history, history.js

I created an client side app using react, redux, saga with help of hash history (in react-router). Now, I am planning to integrate third party authentication system for validating user credentials. Once its validated, then will redirect to my own website with access token. I am able to get accesz token via 2 methods: one is through headers form data and another is hash/query. I used hash/query to get access token in the url like below.

`http://localhost:3000?g=y#access_token=hdhdbbd`

Because of react router hash history, slash '/' will automatically add before the access token and take me to error page. Is there a way to add the hash url before the queryparam without removing the access token like below.

`http://localhost:3000#/about?g=y#access_token=hdhdbbd`

Please give me some suggestion to proceed further.
Thanks - durai

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically get your path through the window object and append anything you'd like to it:

```
getBaseUrl() {
  const {pathname, protocol, host} = window.location;
  return `${protocol}//${host}${pathname}`;
}

render() {
  const redirectUrl = `${this.getBaseUrl()}#/definedPath`;
  return {
    //... use redirectUrl in some action/element for getting your query
  }
}
```

And now, for example, your query param might land here: baseUrl/#/definedPath?queryParam=something